# How can I send a custom desktop notification?

Tags: notification, notify-send

I have a custom script and I want to send a desktop notification (the one that appears in the top right corner of the screen) with a custom message. How do I do that?

Comment: is there a C library that we can bind to for this? It would be nice to not have to launch an extra child process if possible.

Comment: anyone know offhand how to do something similar on MacOS/Macbook pro?

Answer (score 205, accepted):

There are a bunch of other cool features with [`notify-send`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man1/notify-send.1.html)

We can run a command and make it display in the notification:

```
notify-send <title> <`command`>
notify-send Date "`date`"
notify-send Disk "`df / -H`"
```

We can use icons with the notifications

```
notify-send -i <icon> <Message>
notify-send -i face-wink "Hello! January"
```

Really annoying pop up

```
notify-send  -t 0 "Bringing down the system"
```

and

```
notify-send <title> <message>
notify-send "who am i" "I am January"
```

For more options check [here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/NotificationDevelopmentGuidelines)

Comment: Thank you. Where can we get a list of icons, e.g. the `face-wink` that you used?

Comment: check out my answer [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/189231/where-are-the-stock-icon-names-defined-for-the-unity-panel-service-indicators-an/189262#189262)

Comment: `notify-send  -t 0` works but `notify-send "who am i" "I am January"` does not work :( - on ubuntu 15.10

Comment: Worked with `--urgency=critical`

Comment: Installation on debian `sudo apt install libnotify-bin`.

Comment: is there a C library that we can bind to for this? It would be nice to not have to launch an extra child process if possible.

Comment: anyone know offhand how to do something similar on MacOS/Macbook pro?

Answer (score 20):

Just to add to the other answers, when running the command locally from cron, I use

```
DISPLAY=:0.0 /usr/bin/notify-send "TITLE" "MESSAGE"
```

Comment: This may fail if you currently used display appears to be at `:1` or something else. I've noticed such things happen when e.g. Xorg crashes and gets restarted.

Comment: To determine which display is used run echo $DISPLAY in console...

Answer (score 18):

I stumbled upon that one by chance. Answer: use the program [`notify-send`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man1/notify-send.1.html):

```
notify-send "Hello world!"
```

Answer (score 6):

I created a simple and almost-native script that plays Sound and displays a Notification with a Given Message and Time for Ubuntu ([Gist](https://gist.github.com/John-Almardeny/04fb95eeb969aa46f031457c7815b07d)):

```
#!/bin/sh

# https://gist.github.com/John-Almardeny/04fb95eeb969aa46f031457c7815b07d
# Create a Notification With Sound with a Given Message and Time
# The Downloaded Sound is from Notification Sounds https://notificationsounds.com/

MSSG="$1"
TIME="$2"

# install wget if not found
if ! [ -x "$(command -v wget)" ]; then 
    echo -e "INSTALLING WGET...\n\n"
    sudo apt-get install wget
    echo -e "\n\n"
fi

# install at package if not found
if ! [ -x "$(command -v at)" ]; then
    echo -e "INSTALLING AT...\n\n"
    sudo apt-get install at
    echo -e "\n\n"
fi

# install sox if not found
if ! [ -x "$(command -v sox)" ]; then
    echo -e "INSTALLING SOX...\n\n"
    sudo apt-get install sox
    sudo apt-get install sox libsox-fmt-all
    echo -e "\n\n"
fi

# download the noti sound if this is first time
# add alias to the bashrc file
if ! [ -f ~/noti/sound.mp3 ]; then
    echo -e "DOWNLOADING SOUND...\n\n"
    touch ~/noti/sound.mp3 | wget -O ~/noti/sound.mp3 "https://notificationsounds.com/wake-up-tones/rise-and-shine-342/download/mp3"
    sudo echo "alias noti=\"sh ~/noti/noti.sh\"" >> ~/.bashrc
    source ~/.bashrc        
    echo -e "\n\n"
fi

# notify with the sound playing and particular given message and time
echo "notify-send \""$MSSG\"" && play ~/noti/sound.mp3" | at $TIME
```

---

#### How To Use?

#### First Run - Setting Up:

1. Create a new Directory at your home and call it `noti`

   ```
   mkdir ~/noti
   ```
2. Download [noti.sh](https://gist.github.com/John-Almardeny/04fb95eeb969aa46f031457c7815b07d/archive/5502b0060e2a88f3a843b1c5d92c60ad229d7d64.zip)  and extract it to the above `noti` dir.
3. Open Terminal and Change Directory to `noti`

   ```
   cd ~/noti
   ```
4. Make noti.sh executable by issuing:

   ```
   sudo chmod +x noti.sh
   ```
5. Run a Test like this:

   ```
   sh ~/noti/noti.sh "Test" "now"
   ```

---

#### Examples

```
noti "Hello From Noti" "now +1 minute"
noti "Hello From Noti" "now +5 minutes"
noti "Hello From Noti" "now + 1 hour"
noti "Hello From Noti" "now + 2 days"
noti "Hello From Noti" "4 PM + 2 days"
noti "Hello From Noti" "now + 3 weeks"
noti "Hello From Noti" "now + 4 months"
noti "Hello From Noti" "4:00 PM"
noti "Hello From Noti" "2:30 AM tomorrow"
noti "Hello From Noti" "2:30 PM Fri"
noti "Hello From Noti" "2:30 PM 25.07.18"
```

---

#### For Notifying The Finish of Process (example)

```
sudo apt-get update; noti "Done" "now"
```

Answer (score 4):

There is also [zenity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zenity) - universal linux alternative to `notify-send`.

Comment: (Late, I know, but still valid) I disagree that this is an alternative, as `zenity` displays dialog boxes that don't go away by themselves.

Comment: @Noughtnaut, if I remember correct, there is customizable timeout.

Comment: @Noughtnaut on the other hand notify-send's `-t` option is ignored by Ubuntu's Notify OSD and GNOME Shell. I could not make it work even in Xfce. (See the man page of it.)