# Where are the stock-icon-names defined for the unity-panel-service indicators and notify-OSD?

Tags: indicator, icons, notify-osd

[Layout cases](http://Layout_cases_.28with_examples_in_C.2C_Python_and_C.23.29) in the Notification | Ubuntu App Developer document states that

> ... using non-existing (stock-)icon-names ... use one of the new
>   icon-name (see [icons](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/mhall119/devportal/notify-osd#icons)) ...

and that this (icons at http://wiki.ubuntu.com/mhall119/devportal/notify-osd#icons)
 only makes casual reference, via the examples, to

```
... -i notification-message-im
... -i notification-network-wireless-disconnected
```

Presumably

```
... -i notification-network-wireless-connected
```

is also one?
Confirmed via: (interesting icon)

```
notify-send "WiFi icon test" -i notification-network-wireless-connected
```

What other ones are there?

(note that the `icons` link in the source:
wiki.ubuntu.com/mhall119/devportal/notidy-osd#icons
incorrectly spells noti**f**y as noti**d**y)

---

As a consequent of the implications of this answer:

[Where are the stock-icon-names defined for the unity-panel-service indicators and notify-OSD?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/189231/where-are-the-stock-icon-names-defined-for-the-unity-panel-service-indicators-an/189262#189262)

the icons in the above examples could then be found here:
 - `file:///usr/share/notify-osd/icons/gnome/scalable/status/`
 - `file:///usr/share/notify-osd/icons/hicolor/scalable/status/`

However,while there was no icon file named `notification-network-wireless-connected` that string displays `notification-network-wireles.svg` as does `notification-network-wireless-gobledeegook`!

Bookmark:
[Where are the stock-icon-names defined for the unity-panel-service indicators and notify-OSD?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/189231/where-are-the-stock-icon-names-defined-for-the-unity-panel-service-indicators-an)

Answer (score 97, accepted):

`notify-send` uses icon from the `/usr/share/icons/gnome/32x32` (& also `/usr/share/notify-osd/icons/...`)

```
devav2@devav2:/usr/share/icons/gnome/32x32$ ls 
actions  categories  emblems  legacy     places  ui
apps     devices     emotes   mimetypes  status
```

Every directory above (except `legacy`) contains a set of icons available for `notify-send`. For example, emotes contains :

```
devav2@devav2:/usr/share/icons/gnome/32x32$ ls emotes/
emote-love-symbolic.symbolic.png        face-raspberry-symbolic.symbolic.png
face-angel-symbolic.symbolic.png        face-sad-symbolic.symbolic.png
face-angry-symbolic.symbolic.png        face-shutmouth-symbolic.symbolic.png
face-confused-symbolic.symbolic.png     face-sick-symbolic.symbolic.png
face-cool-symbolic.symbolic.png         face-smile-big-symbolic.symbolic.png
face-crying-symbolic.symbolic.png       face-smile-symbolic.symbolic.png
face-devilish-symbolic.symbolic.png     face-smirk-symbolic.symbolic.png
face-embarrassed-symbolic.symbolic.png  face-surprise-symbolic.symbolic.png
face-glasses-symbolic.symbolic.png      face-tired-symbolic.symbolic.png
face-kiss-symbolic.symbolic.png         face-uncertain-symbolic.symbolic.png
face-laugh-symbolic.symbolic.png        face-wink-symbolic.symbolic.png
face-monkey-symbolic.symbolic.png       face-worried-symbolic.symbolic.png
face-plain-symbolic.symbolic.png        face-yawn-symbolic.symbolic.png
```

To use it in `notify-send`, use the prefix before `-symbolic.symbolic.png`:

```sh
notify-send -i face-glasses "I am wearing glasses"
notify-send -i multimedia-player "I am playing music"
```

You can also specify a direct path to an icon :

```sh
notify-send -i /usr/share/pixmaps/gnome-irc.png "Icon Test"
```

Comment: Many Thanks - pursuing rationale of `/usr/share/icons` found example icons in OP here: `file:///usr/share/notify-osd/icons/gnome/scalable/status/` and `file:///usr/share/notify-osd/icons/hicolor/scalable/status/`

Answer (score 21):

I don't know if they're found in a list format somewhere in the hard disk, but there's a list on the web here:

https://specifications.freedesktop.org/icon-naming-spec/latest/ar01s04.html

Comment: Very useful and complete list of icons! I tested some of them and they work.