# Reading Cronjob Output

Tags: command-line, scripts, cron

I have a task setup to run on my `cronjob` where I need to read the output. What I need from the output is the starting character (let's say `A`) and the ending character (let's say `Z`).

`A` helps me understand my script started from the right place, and `Z` helps me understand my script finished at the right place.

So, it is important for me to run that `cronjob`, and see that my output is having proper `A` and `Z`.

I know that not sending the script to `> /dev/null` will try to mail using the MTA, which is not something I want to do. I also don't want to send it to `/dev/null` because I need to read the output.

When I run my script normally from the console (tty), I am able to see the start character (A) and end character (Z), but when I let the `cronjob` run, my script fails to read the start character and complains about `no start characters`.

What can be the problem?

Thank you.

Comment: try [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/23009/reasons-why-crontab-does-not-work) useful link. You could redirect standard output and standard errors using `> /path/to/out/file 2>&1` instead of `> /dev/null`

Comment: Is [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/309853/getting-output-from-a-cron-job-on-the-terminal) a dupe, or did you want it in a file instead of on the terminal emulator?

Comment: It sounds like you're doing two things: a job that produces output whose starting and ending characters are of interest, and a separate script that examines the output. Please show us both--or simplified versions of both, to which the question still fully applies. The most common ways of having one task examine the output of another--piping output from one task to another (or, similarly, using process substitution or command substitution), and having one task log to a file which is read by the other--work exactly the same from a cron job. Right now I think it's unclear what your problem is.