# Can't use the "at" utility

Tags: bash, permissions, schedule

I use Ubuntu 16.04 and try to execute directly on Bash:

```
sudo cat << EOF | at 'now + 1 minute'
echo "hello"
EOF
```

I get:

```
warning: commands will be executed using /bin/sh job 6 
at Wed Dec 28 03:01:00 2016
Can't signal atd (permission denied)
```

So, given there is no permission to run the command, the phrase `hello` won't be echoed on Bash.

If I use `sudo`, why would the permission be denied? Unlike `cd` which isn't a utility but a build-in shell command, `at` (as well as `cat`) are utilities hence `sudo` should apply them.

You might know why at can't be used?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

TL;DR: Move `sudo` across the pipe  (`|`) to the `at` command itself.

#### You haven't really been running `at` as root.

You ran `cat` as root (`sudo cat ...`), and piped the output of `cat` to `at`, but you did not run the `at` command itself as root.

On many systems, some non-root users are permitted to run at jobs. However, if that's not what you want, your system is configured the way you like, and you intend to run this particular at job as root, then you can solve the problem by running `at` as root instead of `cat`. (Either way, you do not need to run `cat` as root in this situation.)

To do that, put `sudo` before `at` instead of `cat`:

```
cat << EOF | sudo at 'now + 1 minute'
```

#### Optional details:

Currently you have:

```
sudo cat << EOF | at 'now + 1 minute'
echo "hello"
EOF
```

That runs `cat` as root with `sudo`, passing `echo "hello"` to it (with here-document syntax). The `cat` command's standard output is piped to the command `at 'now + 1 minute'`, which is *not* run as root. Therefore `at` attempts to schedule the job as the non-root user who ran it (you).

If you want the at job to run as root, you can fix this problem by changing it to:

```
cat << EOF | sudo at 'now + 1 minute'
echo "hello"
EOF
```

If you later configure a non-root user account that you're using to be permitted to run at jobs, *then* you would run *neither* command as root:

```
cat << EOF | at 'now + 1 minute'
echo "hello"
EOF
```

Comment: Hi Eliah. Now it seems to be okay. No errors. Yet, after a minute the phrase "hello" won't be printed on bash... I don't know why because in contrast, `sleep 1m && echo "hello"` will be printed just fine...

Comment: @Benia Output from at jobs doesn't go to the terminal where you ran `at`. As far as `at` could know, that terminal might not be appropriate for such use (or not exist) at the time the command runs. [Instead, the output is mailed to you.](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/82835) But in Ubuntu -- unlike Debian -- [no mail transfer agent is set up by default, so you don't receive the output at all](https://askubuntu.com/a/309945). Do you need standard output from at jobs to go to your terminal, or is this just for testing? Either way, do [any of these answers](https://askubuntu.com/q/309853) help?

Comment: Indeed, I need the stdout in the terminal (the one I type commands to when the timeout ends). Given I prefer not use cron for this, only the answer by Keith Reynolds seems in the direction of what I need, but I don't have much knowledge about printing output in such case and might be wrong.

Comment: I would thank you dearly again Eliah if you would add a small appendix on the end of the answer about how to "pop" into the terminal, the stdout of the commands executed after `at` (even if the session was terminated from any reason).

Comment: @Benia Regarding your comment about needing stdout in the terminal: Are you using this strictly as a way to make things happen in your terminal at a later time while using it interactively? Do you know that your terminal will be open and that you will want to receive the output on it? If so, then are you sure you need to use `at`? Is running a subshell as a background job with `&` -- `(sleep 1m && echo "hello")&` -- sufficient for your needs? (You could replace `1m` with something like `5s` for testing, of course.)

Comment: Roaima comments to answer by Edd that `nohup sleep command` will fail on reboot though: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/332313/how-to-timeout-by-hours-in-bash-and-keep-timing-out-even-if-the-session-was-clo/333004?noredirect=1#comment586568_333004 Or I might miss understand roaima...

Comment: Hey..you're back..welcome and +1 :)

Comment: Running a nohup sleep & so in background is problematic... No popup will happen on working-window.

Comment: I've dedicated a whole new question for our issue here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/865254/how-to-make-at-or-sleep-utilities-to-popup-stdout-on-highest-bash-session