# Why cron not executing script?

Tags: scripts, cron, sh

I create a simply script in **/root/test.sh** file:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "hello"
mkdir newdir
```

next:

```
chmod +x /root/test.sh
```

We can convinced, what
test.sh is owned by root:

```
root@ubuntu-s-1vcpu-1gb-ams3-01:~# find /root -user root /root
/root/test.sh
```

So, my crontab:

```
root@ubuntu-s-1vcpu-1gb-ams3-01:~# crontab -l
SHELL=/bin/bash
PATH=/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin

* * * * * /root/test.sh
```

(Also i did try with run-parts:

```
* * * * * root run-parts /root/test.sh
```

)

No one method not run my script, not out "hello" and not create a newdir directory.

service cron status:

```
root@ubuntu-s-1vcpu-1gb-ams3-01:~# service cron status
● cron.service - Regular background program processing daemon
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/cron.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Sat 2018-08-18 15:46:42 UTC; 23h ago
     Docs: man:cron(8)
 Main PID: 1340 (cron)
    Tasks: 1
   Memory: 26.8M
      CPU: 7.982s
   CGroup: /system.slice/cron.service
           └─1340 /usr/sbin/cron -f

Aug 19 15:16:01 ubuntu-s-1vcpu-1gb-ams3-01 CRON[439]: (root) CMD (root run-parts /root/test.sh)
Aug 19 15:16:01 ubuntu-s-1vcpu-1gb-ams3-01 CRON[438]: (CRON) info (No MTA installed, discarding output)
Aug 19 15:16:01 ubuntu-s-1vcpu-1gb-ams3-01 CRON[438]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
Aug 19 15:17:01 ubuntu-s-1vcpu-1gb-ams3-01 CRON[1032]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Aug 19 15:17:01 ubuntu-s-1vcpu-1gb-ams3-01 CRON[1031]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Aug 19 15:17:01 ubuntu-s-1vcpu-1gb-ams3-01 CRON[1033]: (root) CMD (root run-parts /root/test.sh)
Aug 19 15:17:01 ubuntu-s-1vcpu-1gb-ams3-01 CRON[1032]: (CRON) info (No MTA installed, discarding output)
Aug 19 15:17:01 ubuntu-s-1vcpu-1gb-ams3-01 CRON[1032]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
Aug 19 15:17:01 ubuntu-s-1vcpu-1gb-ams3-01 CRON[1034]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
Aug 19 15:17:01 ubuntu-s-1vcpu-1gb-ams3-01 CRON[1031]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
```

every minutes cron tries do something, but, how I see - I haved message

> session closed for user root

and nothing not happens.

What more I must to do?

========================================================================

after deleting the string MAILTO=name@ukr.net script correctly creats newdir directory. But yet not printed string 'hello'. So it works, but some issue in #echo "hello" string.

Comment: Your script won't output anything, because although you've specified a `MAILTO`, you don't appear to have a mail transfer agent (MTA) running. Try redirecting its output to a log file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run `crontab -e` and put following line in it:

```
*/1 * * * * /root/test.sh 1> /dev/null 2> /root/test.err
```

This is running every minute. The test.err file will give you output error in case the command does not succeed.

Comment: file created, but empty.

Comment: Then your script / command is successful. If you run the script from terminal, is the directory created?

Comment: I already have create directory. Thank you. 
But some issue with #echo command.

Comment: If you want to mail the output of the command use this line:

Comment: echo "mail content" | mail -s "mail subject" your@email.com

Comment: of course sendmail has to be installed.

Comment: Then everything is fine. Poka.

Comment: I just want tested first time using cron, and launch simply bah file, with simply 'hello world' script). And I steel cannot out text in console!

Comment: The cron does not have screen output. You will need to redirect the output to a certain screen. This is relevant for you: https://askubuntu.com/questions/309853/getting-output-from-a-cron-job-on-the-terminal