# Playing an audio with cron jobs

Tags: bash, cron, c

I am trying to add a new command to my own shell such as:

```
alarm 7.15 music.wav
```

I want to create a cron job so it can schedule alarm daily at given time.
So, I create a file for each call of alarm, named `musicFile.txt`

Here is my bash file to run: (musicFile.txt)

```
#!/bin/bash 
15 7 * * * XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/run/user/$(id -u) play -q /home/harun/Desktop/music.wav > alarmFile 
crontab alarmFile 
rm -f alarmFile 
rm -f musicFile.txt
```

And I execute this comment with execvp:

```
bash musicFile.txt
```

However, nothing happens. How should I set an alarm with crontab?

Comment: How do you edit your crontab? Do you use `crontab -e` or `sudo crontab -e`? Do you want to run this alarm only for one user or for each user that could be logged in?

Comment: If @Gryu's answer doesn't work for whoever ends up here, check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43436895/4796762) on SO.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In my case I run crontab using current user session:

```
$ crontab -e

* * * * * /usr/bin/play -q /home/user/test/bell.wav
```

This makes [a sound](https://www.findsounds.com/ISAPI/search.dll?keywords=alarm) playing every minute.

First try using simpler commands.

If you want to configure alarm for different users, you could use `crontab -e` from their terminal sessions. To switch to other user terminal session, use `su username` command.

But, better, instead of using commands with parameters in crontab, use script and specify its path in crontab. Don't forget to `chmod +x yourscriptpath` and also, don't forget to specify full paths to binaries and check your scripts by executing `sh pathtoyour/script.sh`

If you could run the next in terminal:

```
XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/run/user/$(id -u) play -q /home/harun/Desktop/music.wav > alarmFile 
crontab alarmFile 
rm -f alarmFile 
rm -f musicFile.txt
```

Then you could try to add it in your crontab file by `crontab -e` command execution and by editing it:

```
15 7 * * * XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/run/user/$(id -u) play -q /home/harun/Desktop/music.wav > /home/harum/alarmFile && /bin/rm -f /home/harun/alarmFile && /bin/rm -f /home/harum/musicFile.txt
```

To check if it works now, just replace `15 7` by `* *`.

**Script creation:**

```
vim.tiny /home/harum/alarm.sh

#!/bin/bash
XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/run/user/$(id -u) play -q /home/harun/Desktop/music.wav > /home/harum/alarmFile && /bin/rm -f /home/harun/alarmFile && /bin/rm -f /home/harum/musicFile.txt
```

**Making script executable:**

```
chmod +x /home/harum/alarm.sh
```

**Adding script to crontab:**

```
crontab -e

15 7 * * * /home/harum/alarm.sh
```

Finally, as one of commentators suggested, you could use `XDG_RUNTIME_DIR` in your script by specifying the specific user directly (if you want to run your script as root but use other's user id in your script:

```
XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/run/user/$(id yourSpecificUser | awk -F" " '{print $1}' | awk -F"(" '{print $1}' | awk -F"=" '{print $2}')
```

Comment: Thank you, but why I cannot run my bash file? Or how should I prepare a bash file to schedule a crontab like your example?

Comment: @HARUNSASMAZ check answer. I've updated it.

Comment: How should I run the first part you mentioned? Starting with XDG. Just line by line on command line? May I create a bash file and run directly?

Comment: updated answer you could try

Comment: You are great! Thanks a lot

Comment: You're welcome:)

Comment: Hey one more question, if I just want to echo I am done, where the output of echo goes?

Comment: You could analyze this thread: https://askubuntu.com/q/309853/925971

Comment: I've tried `/usr/bin/mpg123 /path/to/some.mp3` in my crontab but it didn't work, I don't hear any audio. If I run it manually, it works fine though.

Comment: You can also find some sound samples on `/usr/share/sounds/freedesktop/stereo/`