# Executable won't execute

Tags: bash, lubuntu, scripts, executable, execute-command

I hope that my post is acceptable although I am actually running lubuntu, not ubuntu.

I am trying to create an executable file but I am having difficulties.

I created a script with a text editor and saved it onto my desktop:

```
#!/usr/bin
echo hello
```

I ran `sudo chmod +x`and `sudo chmod 755` on it.
When I double click on it I get a dialogue box asking me either to execute or execute in terminal as follows:

[image]

When I click on execute, I get `Failed to execute child process "/home/name/Desktop/helloworld" (Permission denied)`

If I click on execute in terminal, I just get a new terminal window with `name@macbook:~/Desktop$` but no sign of my script.

Comment: Why is your shebang `#!/usr/bin`? ..please [read this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_%28Unix%29)

Comment: Just tested this, file named as **test.sh** with **`#!/bin/bash`** as first line. Works fine from command line. *Are you actually trying to create a GUI-executable (icon)?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is most likely caused by your [Shebang](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_%28Unix%29) - the `#!/usr/bin` line in your script.

The Shebang in a script is what tells Ubuntu/Linux/BASH what command to run to interpret or execute the script.

Python script shebangs are usually `#!/usr/bin/env python` or `#!/usr/bin/python` (says to run the script with the Python interpreter) and BASH scripts (like yours is) are usually `#!/bin/bash` (says to run the script in a BASH terminal) or `#!/bin/sh` (run the script with `sh` or shell).

Because `/usr/bin` is a directory, not a program/sym-link to a program, nothing can actually be executed.

Try changing that initial line to be `#!/bin/bash`:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo hello
```

Comment: Sadly nothing has changed except that clicking on execute now does nothing, not even give an error.

Comment: @Dr.Paul That's because you're running the `echo` command, which only outputs to the terminal. Try changing the `echo Hello` line in your script to `notify-send "Hello!" "Hello There!". It'll display a notification. Look [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/187022/how-can-i-send-a-custom-desktop-notification) for more explanation on how to send custom notifications.

Comment: One point, `python` uses `#!/usr/bin/python` or `#!/usr/bin/env python`

Comment: @heemayl True. I've always used the `#!/usr/env/python` one, couldn't remember what the other correct one was. Edited, thanks for pointing that out :)

Comment: Are you sure? there is no `env` directory in `/usr` so no question about `/usr/env/python`..

Comment: @heemayl Whoop! Mis-type. Sorry. I meant `/usr/bin/env python`.